# Android GCM received message always return null

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to do push notifications on android. At server site I am using asp. I can send and receive notifications but cant handle the message that I want to show in notification. Mesaage always returns null. Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Register Service -->

    <service android:name="com.example.pushnotificationexample.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

And there is my GcmIntentService

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        String s=extras.getString("message");
        //try to get message but always return null

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Warning: "
                        + extras.get("message"));
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your server side code and GCM receiver codings.?

Comment: For server side I use this codes http://dotnetprojectsourcecode.blogspot.com.tr/2014/02/google-gcm-send-notification-to-android.html and theGcm receiver : 
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}

Comment: log your data receiving in the receiver and check if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to know if this is a problem from the server sideor client side. You can run a fiddle like this on [phpfiddle.com](http://phpfiddle.com).

```
<?php


// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );


$registrationIds = array("YOUR DEVICE IDS WILL GO HERE" );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'       => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'         => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'      => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'              => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
?>
```

Note: While creating API Access Key on google developer console, you have to use 0.0.0.0/0 as ip address. (For testing purpose).

If this is working properly then it is probably client side code that is maleficent. The most likely fault is that you are reading the wrong property "message", to check the keys insert before extras.getString("message") and look at the log:

```
        Iterator<String> stringIterator = extras.keySet().iterator();
    if (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
        Log.d("a", "Amount of keys sent by server: '" + extras.keySet().size() + "' Existing key" + stringIterator.next());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working I think something wrong with my server side. I use this codes http://dotnetprojectsourcecode.blogspot.com.tr/2014/02/google-gcm-send-notification-to-android.html if it it not too much can you explain me what is wrong in this code.

Comment: You are absolutely sure : var value = TextBox1.Text;  TextBox1.Text is filled right? Can you fill it with: "Example"?